# Relatório de produtividade via git

Tags: git

Como faço para tirar um relatório de produtividade de cada usuário no git( pode ser um programa). Por exemplo: linhas de código inseridas ou alteradas.

Comment: Primeiro, não seria um relatório de produtividade e sim de atuação...

Comment: Linha de código serve entre outras coisas pra medir ineficiência. Geralmente quanto pior o programador, mais linha ele usa para fazer as mesmas coisas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem alguns projetos open source que fazem isso:

- http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/
- https://repo.or.cz/w/git-stats.git
- https://github.com/ejwa/gitinspector